# Create and Add rows to Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm rather new to to VBA coding. I want to set up a template and would like to create a macro that looks at column B. Then creates new worksheets for the different inputs in B. Lastly it then pulls all rows with value "B1" and puts them into the corresponding worksheet.

(Example if unclear) Column B includes the values 1 and 2. Code then creates worksheets called "1" and "2". Then takes all the rows that have 1 in column B and puts them in worksheet "1", and similar for value "2".

```
Sub Sheet() 
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim cellRange As Long

    For Each Worksheets("ImportSheet") In [Column J]
        Set NewSheet = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set NewSheet = Worksheets(rng.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If NewSheet Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = rng.Value
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: I tried a lot of other stuff, but I've just gotten to the point where I don't know where to go with it

Comment: @fungrymonster do you have an header row (row 1) at "ImportSheet" ? so the values start from row 2?

Comment: Yes,they start at row 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code as comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sheet()

Dim lRow    As Long
Dim Dict    As Object
Dim Key     As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim DestSht As Worksheet
Dim ShtName As String

Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With Worksheets("ImportSheet")

    ' loop from row 2 until last row with data in Column "B"
    For lRow = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row          
        ' copy unique values from column B into dictionary
        If Not Dict.exists(.Range("B" & lRow).value) Then
            If .Range("B" & lRow).value <> "" Then Dict.Add .Range("B" & lRow).value, .Range("B" & lRow).value
        End If
    Next lRow

    ' create a new worksheet per unique key in Dictionary
    For Each Key In Dict
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = Key
    Next Key

    ' loop through all cells in Column B, and copy each row to relevant worksheet
    For lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If .Range("B" & lRow).value <> "" Then
            ShtName = .Range("B" & lRow).value
            Set DestSht = Worksheets(ShtName)
            LastRow = DestSht.Cells(DestSht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Rows(lRow).Copy Destination:=DestSht.Range("A" & LastRow)
            .Rows(lRow).Delete xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next lRow
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @fungrymonster  you're welcome, please mark as answer. Y clicking the   V next to my answer

Answer (score -1):

And this is what I had for moving rows:

```
Dim contract As String
Imprt = Worksheets("ImportSheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count
   Srtd = Worksheets(contract)"enter code here"
   If Srtd = 1 Then Srtd = 0
    For x = Imprt To 2 Step -1
        If Range("J" & x).Value = contract Then
            Rows(x).Cut Destination:=Worksheets(contract).Range("A" & Srtd + 1)
            Srtd = Srtd + 1
            Else:
        End If
    Next x
```